# No Way to Close SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql-server, dispose, sqlconnection

I know this is an old question. Thousands of statements on Google say `Connection will be closed in Dispose()`. However, who did really verify that?

I found that a `SqlConnection` is **no way to close**. I have a simple program (with line number on left).

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
1   {
2        var connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
3        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
5        {
6            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("create table #mytable(col1 int);", conn))
7            {
8                conn.Open();
9                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
10           }
11           conn.Close();
12           conn.Dispose();
13       }
14       GC.Collect();
15   }
  }
```

And I have a T-SQL statement for checking active connection

```
exec sp_who2
```

I **stepped line by line** with the Debugger, meanwhile, I checked the active connection with `sp_who2`.

Everyone is expecting the connection should be closed on line 11. Right? However, the connection is in `sleep` after line 11.

Okay, try manually disposal on next line. But after line 12, the connection is still in `sleep`.

Okay, next line is the auto-disposal. But after line 13, the connection is still in `sleep`.

Okay, it may be related to the `GC`. So I explicitly ran `GC.Collect()` to try to collect the `conn` object. But after line 14, the connection is still in `sleep`.

**The connection actually closed after line 15**. That means the end of program.

In the program above, a temp table `#mytable` is created. However, the temp table will only be dropped if the connection is closed. The problem we are facing is `too many temp tables are in the database`. (Yes, I know temp tables should be dropped after use.)

I also tried to

1. use `{ }` to create a new scope to wrap the connection. The result is the same.
2. create a new thread to connect to the DB server. The result is also the same.
3. use `while(true) { Thread.Sleep(1000); GC.Collect(); }` at the end of the `Main` method. The result is also the same.

None of them above can close the SqlConnection. How to close a connection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Connection pooling in ADO.NET is enabled by default.  This means that when you "dispose" your connection, you are merely returning it to the pool.  When you exit the program, you are obviously finally releasing everything from the pool.  If you want to avoid this, you have to opt-out of connection pooling.

To disable, add the `Pooling=false` argument to your connection string:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection(
    @"Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated " +      
    "Security=SSPI;Pooling=false;");
```

Comment: @quofaye, I'm glad it worked for you.  However, you should probably ask yourself whether you really want to disable connection pooling.  While it's certainly satisfying to see your resources go down when you are finished with them, connection pooling serves a very real purpose.  Generally, obtaining new connections is quite costly, and having to allocate a new one without a pool incurs significant overhead in aggregate that is completely eliminated by a pool.

Comment: thanks for your comments. Yes, it is a hard choice between on and off connection pool. However, I just tried to use `SqlConnection.ClearPool(conn)` and the connection is still on. It seems there is no reliable way to close a connection. `Pooling=false` seems to be the only option for my case.

Comment: @quofaye, fair enough -- if you really need to make sure you eliminate your connection when you're done, you're probably right that this is the only option.

Comment: in most cases, you do not need to do this. if the #temp table is the issue, you should drop the temp table explicitly, instead of depending on sql.